# Query Parent Class EF inheritence linq query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, inheritance

Hello everyone so here is my basic EF class structure:

```
public abstract class StandardEngineeredModel
{
    [Key]
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public int VoltageInput { get; set; }
}
public class DualRatedInputEngineeredModel : StandardEngineeredModel
{

    public int SinglePhaseVoltageInput { get; set; }
    public string SinglePhaseHzInput { get; set; }
    public decimal SinglePhaseAmpsInput { get; set; }
    public bool SeparateInput { get; set; }
}
```

And my context:

```
public class LabelPrintingContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<StandardEngineeredModel> StandardEngineeredModels { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is query for a StandardEngineeredModel. Here is an example of a query I tried:

```
public StandardEngineeredModel GetEngineeredOrder(string modelNumber)
    {
        using (context = new LabelPrintingContext())
        {
            return (from s in context.StandardEngineeredModels
                        where s.ModelNumber == modelNumber
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
```

But when executing this it says invalid column name SeparateInput which seems to be happening because of the extra column being added to my StandardEngineeredModels table due to the DualRatedInputEngineeredModel inheriting from it. Not sure how to go about this, I don't want to return an Iqueryable, but no matter what I try it tells me the SeparateInput is an invalid column name.

I also tried casting it first and get the same error:

```
public StandardEngineeredModel GetEngineeredOrder(string modelNumber)
    {
        using (context = new LabelPrintingContext())
        {
            return (from s in context.StandardEngineeredModels.OfType<StandardEngineeredModel>()
                        where s.ModelNumber == modelNumber
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
```

Do I need to make a DTO or something? Am I just doing this completely wrong?

Thanks in advance for any opinions / help!

Comment: Based on the shown code, I don't see where `DualRatedInputEngineeredModel` is every referenced, so I don't see  how that error can occur with this code.

Comment: Exactly. That is why I am confused as to why this error is  coming up.

Comment: Are you using Table-per-Hierarchy or Table-per-Concrete for your schema? TPH is easier to map to access DbSets of the base type, though it should be possible to do with TPC. It sounds like you may want TPC where you'd have a base table and a separate table for the  DualRatedInputEngineeredModel, however EF is thinking it will be TPH where all sub-classes are stored in a single table with a discriminator.

Comment: Because of the way EF creates the tables separateinput is in the standardengineeredmodel table and there is a discriminator to determine what model I'm using.

Comment: I am using TPH, is there no way to pull just the base class properties from the table? I prefer to use TPH but if it can't do what I am needing here I can switch.

Comment: Yes, in that case it should work provided that there are mappings for your sub-classes. You should be able to use a DbSet of the base class, but EF will need to know about the sub-classes as well. Can you include the configuration setup for these classes? (EntityTypeConfiguration or modelBuilder)

Comment: I want to keep using TPH as my structure. If I use mappings to map the inherited entities then it changes it to TPC